# How do I create a heat map from three lists in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I have 3 arrays of data: initial_R, initial_v and E_total.

```py
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib
   import matplotlib as mpl
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import seaborn as sns
   import pandas as pd
   
   initial_R=[]
   initial_v=[]
   E_total=[]
```

I then have a piece of code that fills these three arrays. I wont post it here as its quite long, but it works.

initial_R is the x-coordinate, initial_v is the y-coordinate and E_total is the intensity value at those coordinates. I would like to plot this as a simple heatmap, with each square coloured one of two colours depending on if E_total is positive or negative.

```py
    df = pd.read_clipboard()
    df.drop_duplicates(['initial_R','initial_v'], inplace=True)
    pivot = df.pivot(index='initial_R', columns='initial_v', values='E_total')
    ax = sns.heatmap(pivot,annot=True)
    plt.show()

    print (pivot)
```

I have seen the above code used before, but it doesn't work with my data, not sure how it works to be honest.

Comment: please provide a (minimal) reproducible `df`

Comment: I assume `sns` is Seaborn, right? When asking questions it is important to remember that we don't know the context that you know. So telling us that `pd` is pandas or better yet, show us the code including `import`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.sign` to get the sign of your values:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'initial_R': [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
                   'initial_v': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'E_total': [-1, 2, -4, -3, 0, -1, 5]})

df.drop_duplicates(['initial_R','initial_v'], inplace=True)

pivot = df.pivot(index='initial_R', columns='initial_v', values='E_total')

sns.heatmap(np.sign(pivot), annot=True)
```

If you want to combine 0 and positive values:

```
sns.heatmap(pivot.ge(0).astype(int).mask(pivot.isna()), annot=True)
```

Output 1:

[image]

Output 2:

[image]

If you want custom labels:

```
pivot2 = pivot.ge(0).astype(int).mask(pivot.isna())

sns.heatmap(pivot2, annot=pivot2.replace({0: 'negative', 1: 'positive'}), fmt='s')
```

Output:

[image]